# Can a site's appearance in the Google Suggest dropdown be manipulated?

Tags: seo

A customer has asked this morning why he isn't showing up at all
in the "Google Suggest" (I think it's called) dropdown. He complains that one
of his competitors is the first ranked result in the Google Suggest dropdown.

The competitor's business name is made up of common words (e.g. Widget
Manufacturing) so, sure, he does show up. My customer, whose business name is a proper
name, is totally absent from Google Suggest. It concerns him.

How do Google determine what appears in the Google Suggest dropdown? Is it
something to worry about in terms of SEO? What would be a good response to the customer?

**Update: 2 months later**

He now shows up in Google Suggest ... we didn't change anything. I guess it's just Google being Google

Comment: You mean like widgetco.com comes up when you type in Widget Manufacturing?

Comment: I think that Google Suggest is returning something like "people have searched these terms", so if nobody is searching for "GarbleGronk Corporation", it wouldn't show up. It did work like this in the beginning, not sure if it's the case now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you will have no control over this.  No individual websites show up under Google Suggest anyway, just similar *keywords*.  Tell him his competitor is only showing up because his business name is a common keyword, and that his best bet is to try to get in the top of the search results for that keyword, via organic results or PPC.

Comment: You're right, it isn't an individual website that's showing up in GS. What I mean is ... you pick a match in GS, then the first of the 10 results and that's the competitor's website

Comment: Yeah, so it really has nothing to do with Google Suggest, it's all about doing SEO/PPC for those keywords like you would normally... you just have more of a motivation to do it for those keywords because of GS.

Answer (score 2):

Google suggest is just a listing of commonly searched-for terms.  The reason "Widget Manufacturing" shows up is because a lot of people search for that exact (or a similar) phrase.  Google Suggest has nothing to do with SEO.  You could potentially have a very high listing on Google Suggest and have zero results on Google Search (although, that's highly unlikely).